# RegExp C# and richtextbox

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

Im trying to make the following thing :

1) using regex to match all strings that have the following pattern  "@username" << done i got the pattern  `@([A-z09_-]){4,20}`

2) to parse the text from rich text box and to color those patterns "@somethign" in a color

3) make them clickable & when clicked to insert the clicked string in  text box  ( only if this is possible without tons of code & libraries )

well . thats basically it .. any help is appreciated :) '
Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regexp to find all occurances of "@username", and store them in a collection. Then iterate through this collection and do this:

```
int startpos = 0;
if ( ( startpos = richTextBox1.Find(name) ) > 0 )
{
   richTextBox1.SelectionStart = startpos; 
   richTextBox1.SelectionLength = name.Length;
   richTextBox1.SetSelectionLink(true);
}
```

Note that **this uses an extended richtextbox found here**: [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx). (The SetSelectionLink is not in the vanilla richtextbox class.)